# Remove all files under cache directory using find

Tags: linux, find, exec

I'm trying to use find to remove all files under cache directories in a web hosted environment.

```
find /home/hosted -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "cache" -print -exec rm -rf "{}/*" \;
```

I've tried several variations of this, but for some reason find won't remove the cache/* files.  Anyone see anything I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments for `-exec` don't get expanded as you expect. That is because `-exec` calls execve() directly and thus `*` does not get expanded to all files in a matching directory. If you want to have shell expansion, you have to feed `-exec` with `/bin/sh` (or a shell of your choice), like this:

```
find /your/dir -name "cache" -type d -maxdepth 2 -print -exec sh -c "rm -f {}/*" \;
```